# value not found and look behind errors

Tags: python, regex

I am coding to print between 2 strings of a text,but i get errors:

regex coding:

```
import re
with open("in.txt") as f:
   lines = f.read()
   m = re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=Credit\s*\b).*?(?=Amount)', lines) 
   for i in m:
       print i
```

(returns look behind not found)

Another coding:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    cred_ind = (lines.index("Credit"))
    am_ind = lines.index("Amount")
    print(lines[cred_ind+6:am_ind])
```

(returns substring not found)

Text file:

```
....

accounts
Bank
Credit
 good value
 money
Amount  
Amount
```

Output:

```
good value
money
```

Comment: And there you are again. Almost began to miss you. And again the same question ...

Comment: @miindlek not same question but in same format.i almost got output but then errors!

Comment: `re` module does not have variable length lookbehind, use regex module.

Comment: @hwnd how do it differ from re?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythons `re` module does not support variable length lookbehind.

Simple fix, **avoid** using lookaround assertions..

```
m = re.findall(r'(?s)Credit\s*(.*?)Amount', lines)
```

Comment: it doesnot print anything,by the way it has got two  "Amount" ,please look to that also!

Comment: it wrks perfectly,but only a bit prob is that i dont get correct indentation!

Comment: @hwnd, sometimes the helplessness of the people asking questions here astounds me.